# I am using bluestacks to install ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS but its not working. What should I do?

Tags: system-installation

- I don't have any option to install it through USB Flash Drive or through DVD.

Comment: How do you install ubuntu using bluestacks? Why can't you install using usb or dvd

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're a little confused, **Blue stacks is an android emulator** that allows you to run android applications on your pc, so you **can't install Ubuntu through this program**. Having in mind your limitations (no USB and no CD) you have the following option:

Install **VirtualBox** and run ubuntu on a virtual machine.

Links:

1-  [virtualBox download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

2- [how to use ubuntu on a virtual machine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox)

Hope it helps

Comment: Helpful answer for using VirtualBox. It doesn't surprise me that he doesn't have USB or CD, because installing in Bluestacks is impossible. (PS it doesn't exactly answer the question, but it's helpful!)